# Location of UseRequestLocalization() call in Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-authentication, asp.net-core-localization

I have a custom implementation of `IRequestCultureProvider`. This provider checks if the user is not logged in, then it sets the current culture, otherwise it does not set the culture. Other culture providers would set the current culture, if user is logged in.

In Configure method I use `UseRequestLocalization()` after authentication middleware so that `HttpContext.User` property is populated. However, the property `httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is never true, and it always sets the culture.

The logs show that Culture Provider sets the culture prior to bearer token authentication middleware call, which should populate the `HttpContext.User` property.

I do not understand why.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();

    var defaultRequestCultureProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<DefaultRequestCultureProvider>();

    localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(1, defaultRequestCultureProvider);

    app.Map("/api", webApiApp => ConfigureWebApiBranch(webApiApp,localizationOptions.Value));

    // Removed for brevity

}


private void ConfigureWebApiBranch(IApplicationBuilder webApi, RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions)
{
    webApi.UseCors(Constants.CorsPolicyName);

    webApi.UseAuthentication();

    webApi.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

    webApi.UseMvc();

}
```

I am using IdentityServer4 bearer token authentication middleware.

Answer (score 0):

There was no cookie attached with the request, so authentication was not successful.

Comment: I had the same issue, and I had to call `context.AuthenticateAsync`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48790498/2698119