# CustomRequestCultureProvider: context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-localization

I'm trying to implement a `CustomRequestCultureProvider` in my localization pipeline, to retrieve the user culture from the database. To identify the user, I need the `ClaimsPrincipal`, but for some reason, even though the user is authenticated, `context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always false.

Here's the relevant code (truncated to highlight my issue: authentication is already working; localization code is based on the [localization tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request)).

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("fr"),
                new CultureInfo("en"),
            };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("fr");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

            // we insert at 2, because we want to first check the query, then the cookie, then the DB, then the headers
            options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(2, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
            {
                // ----->> ISSUE IS HERE: this is always false!
                if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    return new ProviderCultureResult("en");

                return null;
            }));
        });

        services
            .AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
            .AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            ;

        return services;
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseRequestLocalization();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        return app;
    }
}
```

What should I do to retrieve the `ClaimsPrincipal` in my `CustomRequestCultureProvider`?

Note: changing the registration order (calling `app.UseAuthentification` before `app.UseRequestLocalization` doesn't fix the issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by manually calling the authentication pipeline. I suspect I need to do that because the `Authorize` attribute is triggered later in the middleware pipeline, and thus it's too early to retrieve the `ClaimsPrincipal` (I might be wrong).

In any case, here's how I modified my `CustomRequestCultureProvider`:

```cs
// we insert at 2, because we want to first check the query, then the cookie, then the DB, then the headers
options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(2, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
{
    // retrieve the ClaimsPrincipal from the cookies
    // note: this is dependent on how your authentication is set up
    var authResult = await context.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    if (!authResult.Succeeded)
        return null;

    var user = authResult.Principal;
    if (user != null)
        return new ProviderCultureResult("en");

    return null;
}));
```

Comment: One year later, I found the issue: I used a `CookieProvider` in addition to using ASP.NET Core identity, and that prevented things from working properly. After removing the `AddCookie` call, I can finally access the `ClaimsPrincipal` in my middleware..

Answer (score 10):

Just in case anybody runs into this in the future I had a similar issue in ASP.NET Core 2.1 and it turned out that I was registering the authentication middleware after inserting the `CustomRequestCultureProvider`.  To fix it I moved `app.UseAuthentication()`  above `options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(...`

Comment: Could you add your `Startup.cs` file? I'm still having the same issue after reorganizing the middleware's order.

Comment: Perfect answer... you saved my day.... I moved my localization logic underneath app.UseAuthentication() and it worked perfectly.

Comment: for the ones that are having similar issue in Core 3.1, Move "app.UseAuthentication();" Above: var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);